# How can I change the background in a free boostrap template?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, background

This boostrap css code about background image.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23343a40' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M2 5l6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
```

And I tried to rename img file to another but It didn't work. Either when I try to add image in
index.html and name was bg.jpg it didn't change the img that I paste the file.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What you have shown so far, lacks context. We can't even see what the CSS property you have shown, is supposed to actually apply to. Please get into the habit of presenting a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your actual CSS configurations are correct and you still can't see your changes live, the reason could be that sometimes browsers do cache the CSS, so this is the reason that you may not see your changes.

You need to clean the cache - try to do that on going to history -> clear cache

or by pressing ctrl+F5

[Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en) is a guide to clear cache on chrome